# How to execute a function at start in Emacs

Tags: emacs, startup, autoexec

I want start following function (from [Replace one space by two after sentences in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43409778/replace-one-space-by-two-after-sentences-in-emacs/)) to run when I right click a file in file-manager to open the document with Emacs.

```
(defun space12 ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "\\. \\([^ ]\\)" nil t)
      (replace-match ".  \\1" t))))
```

This converts `". "` to `".  "` without increasing spaces of existing two space occurrences.

How can this be done. I thought of adding (space12) to init.el but it seems to be loaded before the document is loaded.

Sample input:

```
This is for test. This is second line with only one space at start.  This is third line which already has 2 spaces before it. End of document.
```

Comment: Is this for a particular type of file? I'd probably add a hook to an appropriate major mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your init.el:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'space12)
```

However this will run your function on **every** file you open. Is that what you want?

Comment: Can we use it with `--eval` ?